# How do I identify on which thread a Lua script is running?

Tags: logging, lua

I'm currently working on Lua scripts to integrate with some third party product. This third party product calls my Lua script on several threads at the same time, which is fine. However, as I write to a log file from my scripts, I'd like to identify which thread is running my Lua script and write that to the log file as well.

This would allow me to identify which log entries belong together.

Any thoughts on how I could make a proper distinction between log entries from different threads in Lua would be very welcome.

Comment: Are you talking about lua coroutines or actual preemptive threads that require underlying OS support?

Comment: @greatwolf: I'd prefer to have the thread id from the thread created in the C code that calls my LUA. However if that poses a problem or makes it to complex, I'd settle for any other mechanism to distinguish between threads in my logs.

Comment: The only way to do that is to get access to the underlying OS api from Lua. In windows this would be `GetCurrentThread` or `GetCurrentThreadId`. If FFI is available you can use that to bind to those functions right from lua. Otherwise, you'll likely need to expose those functions with a Lua C extension module.

Comment: @greatwolf , or You can pass and store some identification id while starting new Lua VM on another thread. Like each Lua VM has a thread identification ID on it's registry or something like that.

OR You could wrap lua_State to some another struct which would hold a thread ID You've generated.

Answer (score 3):

The default [`tostring()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-tostring) representation of a table contains the (memory) address of the table. It's guaranteed to be unique across different Lua VMs running on the same process.

You can exploit this to generate a unique ID for each thread:

```lua
local unique_id = tostring( {} ):sub(8) -- extracts the "address" part

print(unique_id)
--> outputs 0x7f876b608b00
```

---

As a side note, this is a recommended way of generating unique keys for use with the global Lua [registry](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.5)!

Comment: This code results in an exception: bad argument #2 to 'sub' (number expected, got no value)

Comment: I've changed the code to this:
local unique_id = tostring( {} )
and used it as string.sub(unique_id, 8)